# CSS design issues with separating icons from each other

Tags: html, css, css-position, positioning

I'm trying to replicate a website, but there are some CSS issues I can't figure the answer to. For right now, what I would like to have my black navigation bar appear like the image below.and here is my code http://jsfiddle.net/FLWb5/1/ I need to replicate this as part of a coding challenge, should I be building this on a css framework, what is the best way

[image: website screenshot]

This is a part of the code which points to the black nav bar icons:

```
<div id="content">
<div id="left_nav_bar">
    <i class="ss-icon">home</i>
    <i class="ss-icon">time</i>
    <i class="ss-icon">user</i>
    <i class="ss-icon">question</i>
    <i class="ss-icon">play</i>
</div>
```

Comment: you should also try to give `max-width`, `min-height` and `max-height` and `min-height` beause they solve hte problem of resolution. i mean if you zoomin and zoomOUt in you page then moste of the thing will go out of their margin.

Comment: -1. You should accept an anwser if somebody took their time to help you.

Answer (score 0):

Try to give `z-index:-1;` to your vertical element.

Also research about `z-index` in CSS.

Hope you manage it.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<div id="content">
    <div id="left_nav_bar">
        <i class="ss-icon">home</i><hr>
        <i class="ss-icon">time</i><hr>
        <i class="ss-icon">user</i><hr>
        <i class="ss-icon">question</i><hr>
        <i class="ss-icon">play</i>
    </div>
```

And CSS:

```
hr {
    border: 0; border-top: 1px solid gray; }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your html/css is so messy so I took some time to fix a easy fiddle for you to get the idea of how to do what you want. Don't mind the colours and all that it's just a simple demo. Is there anything else you want from this demo let me know.

**EDIT with the nav items**
[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/3EwNG/1/)

Hope this helps

```
<div class="container clearfix">
<div class="nav">
    <a href="#" class="nav__link"></a>
    <a href="#" class="nav__link"></a>
    <a href="#" class="nav__link"></a>
    <a href="#" class="nav__link-last"></a>
</div>

<div class="timeline">
    <div class="timeline__line"></div>
    <div class="timeline__item clearfix">
        <div class="timeline__day"></div>
        <div class="timeline__icon"></div>
        <div class="timeline__text"></div>
    </div>

   <div class="timeline__item clearfix">
        <div class="timeline__day"></div>
        <div class="timeline__icon"></div>
       <div class="timeline__text"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

```
.clearfix:after {
  content:"";
  display:table;
  clear:both;
}

/* nav start */

.nav {
    position: relative;
    float: left;
    width: 80px;
    height: 400px;
    background-color: #111;
}

.nav__link {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    height: 60px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #dcdcdc;
}

.nav__link-last {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 60px;
    border-top: 1px solid #dcdcdc;
    background-color: #999;
}

/* nav end */

/* timeline start */

.timeline {
    position: relative;
    float: left; 
    width: 300px;
    height: 400px;
    background-color: #f9f9f9;
}

.timeline__line {
    position: absolute;
    height: 100%;
    width: 2px;
    top: 0;
    left: 80px;
    background-color: #dcdcdc;
}

.timeline__item {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 100;
    width: 100%;
    min-height: 40px;
    margin-top: 30px;
}

.timeline__day {
    float: left;
    width: 62px;
    min-height: 40px;
    background-color: aqua;
}

.timeline__icon {
    float: left;
    width: 40px;
    height: 40px;
    border-radius: 25px;
    background-color: #111;
}

.timeline__text {
    float: left;
    min-width: 100px;
    min-height: 40px;
}

/* timeline end */
```

Comment: Great! What is the best way for me to replicate a website for a coding challenge? Should I start with a css framework? If so, do you know of any good ones

Comment: @stack_newbie23 Depending how challenging you want it to be. The biggest challenge is to start from scratch. But as it being time consuming and lets say you want to do the website responsive, I would start with twitter bootstrap http://getbootstrap.com/